# How to start & who should start first interview over Skype?

Tags: communication

I'm new to freelancing, and I recently sent a few proposals for jobs. Two clients (individuals, not companies) asked me for my Skype id and added me on Skype, but no one has interviewed me yet.

- What is the appropriate way to start the conversation?
- Should I initiate the conversation, or should I wait for them to call me?
- Is it okay to start it via chat (to ask for details about project or when they have time) or are the only appropriate ways voice and/or video?

Answer (score 5):

From what you have said it sounds like they haven't decided to use your services for their project yet, but they wanted your contact information should they choose to use your services.

Now that you have sent them your Skype information here is what you should do.

1. Set yourself working time every day that you are willing to work.

   - This will show that you have a steady Freelance work schedule.
2. Log on to Skype during those times religiously.
3. Be close to your computer during the times that you are connected to Skype

   - The could contact you at any time and will want a prompt response to show them that you are working during your work hours.
4. Be constructive while you wait

   - Make sure that you have your schedule handy, and be prepared to write a new project in.
5. Make sure that you are "Dressed to Impress"

   - They will be able to see you if they choose a video call, so be prepared for that

Then all there is to do is wait for them to contact you, they haven't decided whether you are the right person for the job.

Something that you can do in the mean time while you are waiting for them to contact you is study up on their company so that you know who they are and what they are about (even who they are if it is an individual) it helps to know who you are talking to sometimes.

Comment: That you......?

Comment: oops thank you for pointing that out @mxyzplk

Answer (score 3):

I would start with an email to schedule a date and time, and possibly send your details if you haven't already.

I would wait for their reply regarding the available date and time before discussing about the project.

Answer (score 0):

First the title, the interview has to be initiated by the interviewer, them in this case.

1. An email would be the best to continue a conversation that stopped a while ago after getting your details. A text chat will be my 2nd preference.
2. Depends on how much time has passed. If it is just 2-3 days, wait. But if it is too long (like a month or more), may be they have abandoned the project for some reasons or completed it already. In case it is neither too long not too little time after your first conversation, trying to talk may work for you.
3. Subject to the timelines mentioned above, you can initiate a text chat asking for the appropriate time to talk. Voice/Video for the first time is never a good idea when you are a candidate.

Answer (score 0):

It happens! no need to worry. They will surely contact you. What you can do is to send them an mail saying. As I have already sent you my skype ID and I am waiting for revert to schedule skype meeting regarding your project. Kindly revert with timings so that I can schedule my other project accordingly.

I am sure they will get back to you. It will be preferable to send them an official email first.

Thanks!